# Add table row after certain Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I here trying to add a new row onclick event of button, it suppose to be added after a certain row `<tr class="email">`.

here sample code I am trying

html :

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>phone</td>
    <td>akfg</td>
    <td>akfg</td>
    <td>akfg</td>
    <td>akfg</td>
</tr>
<tr class="email">
    <td>email</td>
    <td>akfg</td>
    <td>akfg</td>
    <td>akfg</td>
    <td>akfg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>im</td>
    <td>akfg</td>
    <td>akfg</td>
    <td>akfg</td>
    <td>akfg</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button>click me</button>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var strVar = "";
strVar += "  <tr>";
strVar += "        <td>email<\/td>";
strVar += "           <td>akfg<\/td>";
strVar += "           <td>akfg<\/td>";
strVar += "           <td>akfg<\/td>";
strVar += "           <td>akfg<\/td>";
strVar += "    <tr>    ";
strVar += "        ";

var priIm = true;

$('button').on('click', function () {
    if (priIm) {
        $('table').append(strVar);
        priIm = false;
    } else {
        (strVar).insertAfter($('tbody .email'));
    }
  });
});
```

and yes have tried `append()` function as well. **[link](http://jsfiddle.net/YUVxH/3/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `after()` instead of `insertAfter()`

```
$('button').on('click' , function(){
  if(!priIm){
    $('table').append(strVar);
      priIm = true;
    }else{
       $('table').find('.email').after(strVar)
   }
});
```

check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YUVxH/15/).

Answer (score 3):

use `.after()` like this -

```
$('tr.email').after(strVar);
```

Demo `---->`  http://jsfiddle.net/p3qKS/

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your `strVar` variable to jQuery object using `$` so that `strVar` is able to utilize jQuery method:

```
   $(strVar).insertAfter($('table').find('.email'));
// ^ here ---
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YUVxH/17/)**

Answer (score 0):

use `.after()` instead of `.append()`

```
    $('.email').after(strVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

I edit your code and its worked,

edit like this and use append()

```
    $(function(){
        $("button").on('click', function(){
            var data = $("table tr:first").html();
            $("table").find('.email').append(data);
        });
    });
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/S4nG9/)

Answer (score 0):

This will work -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var strVar="";
strVar += "  <tr>";
strVar += "        <td>phone<\/td>";
strVar += "           <td>akfg<\/td>";
strVar += "           <td>akfg<\/td>";
strVar += "           <td>akfg<\/td>";
strVar += "           <td>akfg<\/td>";
strVar += "    <tr>    ";
strVar += "        ";
var priIm  = false;

    $('button').on('click' , function(){
    if(!priIm){
        $('table').append(strVar);
        priIm = true;
    }else{
      $(strVar).insertAfter('tr.email');
    }
   });



});
```

You missed to **wrap '`strVar`' in `$()`** and then **`insertAfter` takes the `selecter`** as parameter, as per what I saw in docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can update to this use `.after() or .insertAfter()`:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $('table').find('.email').after(strVar);
});
```

or this:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $(strVar).insertAfter($('table').find('.email'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

```
"$('table .email').after(strVar);"
```

Instead of

```
"$('table').append(strVar);"
```